# Green's Theorem in the Plane: Circulation Density

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis, greens-theorem, curl

The following is from Chapter 16.4: *Green's Theorem in the Plane*, *Thomas's Calculus, 14th Edition*:

> Circulation rate around rectangle $\approx \left( \dfrac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}} - \dfrac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}} \right) \Delta x \Delta y $.
>
> We now divide by $\Delta x \Delta y$ to estimate the circulation rate per unit area or *circulation density* for the rectangle:
>
> $\dfrac{\text{circulation around rectangle}}{\text{rectangle area}} \approx \left( \dfrac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}} - \dfrac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}} \right)$
>
> We let $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ approach zero to define the *circulation density* of $\mathbf{F}$ at the point $(x, y)$.

The above explanation is in reference to the following image:

[image]

And here is some further context:

[image]

What I don't understand is why we let $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ approach zero to define the *circulation density* of $\mathbf{F}$ at the point $(x, y)$? If we divide the circulation rate around the rectangle $\left( \left( \dfrac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}} - \dfrac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}} \right) \Delta x \Delta y \right)$ by the rectangle area $\left( \Delta x \Delta y \right)$, then the $\Delta x \Delta y$ terms just cancels out, so that $\dfrac{\text{circulation around rectangle}}{\text{rectangle area}} \approx \dfrac{ \left( \dfrac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}} - \dfrac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}} \right) \Delta x \Delta y }{ \Delta x \Delta y } = \left( \dfrac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}} - \dfrac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}} \right)$.

So I don't understand why the authors throw in "We let $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ approach zero to define the *circulation density* of $\mathbf{F}$ at the point $(x, y)$." From reading this sentence, it seems that they're trying to do something similar to the limit definition of derivatives, but, as I said, I'm not sure what this is supposed to mean in this context, nor am I sure of what purpose it's supposed to serve since, as I just demonstrated, the algebra neatly gets us the circulation density without limits?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: When$\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are "big" we only have an approximation, just like $f(x+\Delta x) - f(x) \approx f'(x) \, \Delta x$ when it comes to ordinary derivatives. There are actually higher order terms: $f(x+\Delta x) - f(x) = f'(x) \, \Delta x + a \, \Delta x^2 + b \, \Delta x^3 + \cdots$. By taking the limit we only get the first order coefficient.

Comment: @md2perpe  Ahh, yes, of course! The reasoning looks similar to that used in Riemann sums/integrals. The example given is within the context of a rectangle — not a point. And so, in order to get the circulation density of $\mathbf{F}$ at a point $(x, y)$, we must let the “displacements” $\Delta x$ in the $x$-direction and $\Delta y$ in the $y$-direction go approach $0$. Thank you for the clarification!