# Green's Theorem Concepts: Circulation in R2

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I am trying understand how circulation density arises in Green's theorem and I'd like to know if my line of thinking is on the right track. Here it goes :).

**Idea**

We know that if we have a vector field $\vec F=P\hat x+Q\hat y\in\mathbb{C}^1$ on an open region $D$ containing the simple region $R$ whose boundary is $\Gamma$, then we can “cut” $\Gamma$ into $K$ positively-oriented rectangular paths such that $\Gamma=\bigcup_{k=1}^K\Gamma_k$.

Consequently,

$$\oint_\Gamma \vec F\cdot d\vec r=\sum_{k=1}^K \oint_{\Gamma_k}\vec F\cdot d\vec r $$

which says the the macroscopic circulation of $\vec F$ along the curve $\Gamma$ is equal to the sum of microscopic circulations over the region $R$ enclosed by $\Gamma$.

Moreover, we know that the circulation along one of these rectangles is

$$\oint_{\Gamma_k}\vec F\cdot d\vec r=\bigg(\frac{Q(x+\Delta x,\;y)-Q(x,y)}{\Delta x}-\frac{P(x,\;y+\Delta y)-P(x,y)}{\Delta y}\bigg)\;\Delta x\Delta y$$

(for proof, see
[Green's Theorem in the Plane: Circulation Density](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853148/greens-theorem-in-the-plane-circulation-density)).

Hence, the circulation density, or curl, of $\vec F$ at any point $(x,y)$ in $R$ is given by

$$\text{curl}\vec F(x,y)=\lim_{\Delta A\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\Delta A}\oint_\Gamma \vec F \cdot d\vec r=Q_x-P_y,$$

which is a scalar function.

Now, if we let $\sigma (x,y) = Q_x-P_y$ and integrate over the $R$, we obtain

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m\sigma(x^*_{ij},y^*_{ij})\Delta x\Delta y $$

hence,

$$\lim_{n,m\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m\sigma(x^*_{ij},y^*_{ij})\Delta x\Delta y =\iint_R \sigma(x,y) dxdy=\iint_R (Q_x-P_y )dA$$

whose RHS can be related back to the line integral $\oint_\Gamma\vec F\cdot d\vec r$ giving us what we know as Green's Theorem.

Comment: Looks very much like the standard proof of the general Stokes theorem for differential forms which is using simplexes.

Comment: I appreciate your reply :)

Comment: If anyone would like to add anything, please feel free to do so. Any additional insight or suggestions will be most welcome :)

Comment: Your line of thinking is correct. In 2D the circulation of the vector field $(P,Q)$ is $(Q_x-P_y).$